# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Yes, policy' while fitting to my Logistic Regression Model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am reading an excelsheet using pandas, the excelsheet has columns more than 10, out of which I am only interested in 3, so I read it, remove the rows which have Null values and then creating test and a validation set. While fitting it to the Logistic regression Model, I am getting an error

Here's the code

```
train, tv = train_test_split(df1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
test, val = train_test_split(tv, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Logistic Regression
lr = LogisticRegression()
logit_model = lr.fit(train, test)
```

The stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 22, in <module>
    logit_model = lr.fit(train, test)
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 1344, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype,
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 433, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 871, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 673, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "F:\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1990, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Yes, policy'
```

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
 ID      ANSWER                                           TEXT
0  24100.0  Yes, policy  Source text snippet:The ACS Group combines its...
1  24100.0  Yes, policy  Source text snippet:The ACS Environmental Poli...
2  24100.0  Yes, policy  Source text snippet:The ACS Environmental Poli...
3  24100.0  Yes, policy  Source text snippet:6. CONTENTS OF THE ENVIRON...
4  24100.0  Yes, policy  Source text snippet:6. CONTENTS OF THE ENVIRON...
```

By looking at the valueerror I thought that It might be because of the commma after Yes in Answer column, but even after removing it gave the same error. The ID in excel looks like 24100 but when I check its type in dataframe it shows as float64 and is displayed as 24100.0. I am not getting the point, like why is it throwing an error while fitting it on the model.

Comment: The issue isn't the content of the text string it's the fact that it's text at all. You'll need to convert the text to some kind of numerical value. You might consider converting it to a categorical variable: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html). You'll have the same issue with the TEXT column though and depending on how many unique values that contains a categorical variable may not perform well with the logistic regression.

Comment: @BrendanA. thanks alot for your help..will keep that in mind.

Comment: Is that `Yes, Policy`  present in `Answer` column ?

Comment: @AdarshWase Its there, you can see it in the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `ANSWER` and `TEXT` columns contains categorical values, and you have to encode them in numeric form before feeding it to the model. Because machine learning models don't understand text. Use this code on the dataframe before using `train_test_split`

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

    df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].astype('str')
    df['ANSWER'] = df['ANSWER'].astype('str')
        
    df[['ANSWER', 'TEXT']] =  df[['ANSWER', 'TEXT']].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

Also, it's a multi-class classification problem, so `Logistic Regression` isn't going to give you good results. Use `RandomForestClassifier`.

Comment: Please note that, `df` in above code is dataframe name. Please change it accordingly. And `TEXT` and `ANSWER` are the column that contain text, if you have any other text column, then add that column name it in that list.

Comment: Thanks alot for your prompt response, Initially I thought to check with Logistic Regression and then if the accuracy is less then try RandomForest.. however I get a ``` TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'int', 'str']```  on the piece of code you wrote

Comment: I assume that, in one column, you have numbers and string.
In this case, you need everything to be encoded as a string if you want to consider them as categories.

Comment: Yeah, we have to convert the `dtype` of those columns to `str`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I tried using multiple models but all of them are giving me a lot less accuracy...for instance Random Forest Classifier gives me an accuracy of 0.1147. Am I doing something wrong..?

Comment: Yes, with only 3 columns/features, how could a model learns ? You said you've 10 columns, use them all. Each column has some information.

Comment: But i'm only interested in three, so why do I use all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235184/discussion-between-adarsh-wase-and-technophile-3).